# Пользовательская функция преобразования даты

Tags: php, дата

В поле ввода (в input) вводится дата с помощью datepickera в формате `ММ/ДД/ГГГГ`, 
пытаюсь преобразовать дату в формат `ГГГГ-ММ-ДД` (т.е. для `mysql`). Для этого сделал так :

```
function dateformat ($var = ""){
    $var = substr_replace($var, null, 0, 3);
    $var = strtotime($var) ; 
    $var = date('Y-m-d', $var);
    return $var ; 
}

$incoming_date = dateformat($_POST['incoming_date']) ;

echo $incoming_date ; 
exit ;
```

но он мне показывает дату `1970-01-01`. В чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понятно зачем строка `$var = substr_replace($var, null, 0, 3);`
Если её убрать то все получится

Comment: и в натуре всё получилось. Спасибо Вам ! ПОчему то  думал заменять слеши..ступил